# Angular Jasmine testing having a service stub for a private service, then checking if a function to the private service is called?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, stub, angular-test

I am testing an angular component, one of the functions is calling a 'notification service' that is private. I am providing a stub for this service anyway for various reasons during testing.

Now the problem that I'm having is I'm still getting the error `'notification is a private service'` when trying to run a simple check for it.

```
expect(component.notification.done()).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

On my testbed, I have:

```
  { provide: NotificationService, useClass: NotificationStub }
```

and in my NotificationStub class I just have the functions inside with a return;

How can I check if a function is being called if that service is private? I don't want to make it public for various maintainability reasons.

Comment: Can't you just make the equivalent function public in the stub, spy on it and test if it's been called?

Comment: But it's a service that is injected in the constructor. How do I modify that?

Comment: There has got to be more going on here than what you have detailed so far.  Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53208509?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts) where I inject a spy object in place of a private service and it works fine.  Feel free to fork that stackblitz, replace with your own data and show the error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const doneSpy = spyOn(NotificationStub.prototype, 'done')` to install a spy onto `done` method. Then, you can make assertions for `doneSpy` rather than trying to get the private service.

Here is an example using `angular` v11+:

`example.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';

@Component({})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private notification: NotificationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.notification.done();
  }
}
```

`notification.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
  done() {
    console.log('Your real implementation');
  }
}
```

`example.component.spec.ts`:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';

class NotificationStub {
  done() {
    console.log('fake implementation');
  }
}

fdescribe('53366751', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
  let component: ExampleComponent;
  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ExampleComponent],
        providers: [
          { provide: NotificationService, useClass: NotificationStub },
        ],
      })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
    })
  );

  it('should pass', () => {
    const doneSpy = spyOn(NotificationStub.prototype, 'done').and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(doneSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
LOG: 'fake implementation'
Chrome Headless 80.0.3987.87 (Mac OS 10.13.6): Executed 0 of 36 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome Headless 80.0.3987.87 (Mac OS 10.13.6): Executed 2 of 36 (skipped 34) SUCCESS (0.105 secs / 0.024 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
```

test coverage:

[image]